# How to fix kube-proxy Unknown proxy mode "", assuming iptables proxy issue?

Tags: kubernetes, kube-proxy

I'm new to K8s and struggling with some problems with kube-proxy. I have a service that needs to expose the deployment. Everything seems correct but it does not expose it. I found the problem in kube-proxy logs.

```
Unknown proxy mode "", assuming iptables proxy
```

No output for the command iptables-save | grep hostnames

I thought adding `--proxy-mode` into the kube-proxy manifest would resolve my issue and couldn't find it.

I also tried to check the config file with this command:

```
ps -ef | grep kube-proxy
```

Output:

```
root      1423 24476  0 12:12 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto kube-proxy
root      8424  8392  0 11:45 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/bin/kube-proxy --config=/var/lib/kube-proxy/config.conf --hostname-override=
ip-10-0-0-100.us-west-2.compute.internal
root@ip-10-0-0-100:~# find /var/lib/kube-proxy/config.conf
find: ‘/var/lib/kube-proxy/config.conf’: No such file or directory
root@ip-10-0-0-100:~# find  /usr/local/bin/kube-proxy
find: ‘/usr/local/bin/kube-proxy’: No such file or directory
```

Any leads to help me find my way would highly be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you share details about how you run kube-proxy?

Comment: I am doing a practice test for CKA exam. So I'm troubleshooting the issue. I can check something you want if you know what might cause this issue? @whites11

Comment: Well, to begin with "Unknown proxy mode" is not an error just a warning. My guess is that the path of kube-proxy in the manifest that runs it is wrong and you need to adjust it. You need to find how it is deployed

Comment: @whites11 that was my question actually. I knew I could resolve the issue. I just cant find how to find the proper manifest for kube-proxy. As I said this is a practical lab exam question so it does not provide how kube-proxy is deployed.

Comment: Normally kube-proxy is deployed as a daemonset in kube-system namespace. If you don't have to fix a deployment pipeline but just the status quo of the cluster try checking if there is such daemonset

Comment: I added a comment about how kube-proxy is usually deployed. Did you check that? There is no progress I can make with the information I currently have

Comment: Thank you for following up @WytrzymałyWiktor I have figured it out. The problem was a network policy.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason could be the network plugin not being installed out of many possibilities.

In my case, when I received the below error, I wanted to check for the installed CNI plugin.

```
Unknown proxy mode "", assuming iptables proxy
```

- Check installed CNI plugin with below command,

  ```sh
  $ ls /etc/cni/net.d
  ```
- Suppose, it's a `weave-net`. Then we must look for the objects created for this plug-in with `k get all -n kube-system`. In my case, I didn't find any objects created for the weave-net. Thus I just installed weave with the below command,

  ```sh
  $ kubectl apply -f "https://cloud.weave.works/k8s/net?k8s-version=$(kubectl version | base64 | tr -d '\n')"
  ```

---

One more thing to keep in mind,

`/var/lib/kube-proxy/config.conf` is the mounted location inside the **kube-proxy pod**. Check the details of ConfigMap named kube-proxy.

```
kubectl describe configmap kube-proxy -n kube-system
```